# PHP object overflow

Tags: php, object, constructor

I'm trying to organize classes in a project in a fashion similar to:

```
$TheRoberts = new family;

class family {
    public function __construct() {
        $bobby = new father;
        $cindy = new daughter;
    }
}

class father extends family {
    function PayBills() {}
    function GoToWork() {}
}

class daughter extends family {
    function AskForMoney() {}
    function GoToSchool() {}
}
```

Literature on the subject is pretty abstract, but, if I understand correctly, this is how it's done. Why, then, is PHP throwing errors about memory exhaustion and exceeding execution times? In short: why is the constructor looping?

Comment: Not related, but PHP classes are usually UpperCamelCased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling new family is then calling new daughter, which is itself a child class of family, so therefore calling the family constructor which is calling new daughter...

Daughter and father should not extend family... You should create a family_member class which daughter and father extend (an is-a) relationship. Then the family could have family_members (has-a relationship).

Comment: Jordan, thanks for editing. My iPhone seems to like to replace constructor with constrictor.

Answer (score 1):

Your `father` and `daughter` classes don't define a constructor, so they will inherit the constructor from `family`. This will cause infinite number of `father` objects to be created.

In this particular example, neither `father` or `daughter` should extend the `family` class.